# Dirty Forms giving error when I try to set form to clean

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery-dirtyforms

I have a form that I am trying to monitor to see when it becomes "Dirty" (changed), so that I can then enable a Save Changes button. It's fairly simple. In the $(document).ready() section, I enable dirtyForms on my form.

```
$(".dirtyForm").dirtyForms();
```

Then, I load the form from an ajax call, and inside that same function, I set it to clean and then start calling a function to check when it's dirty.

```
$(".dirtyForm").dirtyForms("setClean");
constant = setInterval(function(){checkDirty()}, 500);
```

Here is my function to check for when this becomes Dirty. Btw, if anyone knows of a better way to do this part, please let me know.

```
function checkDirty(){
    if ($.DirtyForms.isDirty()){
        $(".saveDirtyForm").removeAttr("disabled");
            $(".resetDirtyForm").removeAttr("disabled");
            console.log("Dirty...");
            clearTimeout(constant);
    }
}
```

You will notice that in the checkDirty function, it has clearTimeout(constant) to stop the function from continually repeating after the form becomes dirty. This all up to this point works fine. The buttons stay disabled until I change something and then almost immediately become enabled. The problem comes when I recall the ajax function to load the form with more info. When it resets the form, it gives an error when it's set to clean. It says,

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function ( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context, rootjQuery );
} has no method 'facebox'
```

This error is in the jquery.dirtyForms.js file. It doesn't set the form to clean and start the monitoring function again. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the function that zeroflagL was asking about.

```
        function getOrderDets(id){
        $.ajax({
            url: DONEP+"blueBlob/donors/"+donorID+"/orders/"+id,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                dataSec = data.main.aResultData[0];
                //Clear Fields
                $("#orderIdTag").text('');
                $("#orderNum").val('');
                $("#doPlaced").val('');
                $("#doShip").val('');
                $("#dTrack").val('');
                $("#doNote").val('');
                //Set Main fields
                $("#orderIdTag").text(dataSec.OrderID);
                $("#orderNum").val(dataSec.OrderNumber);
                $("#doPlaced").val(dataSec.OrderDate);
                $("#doShip").val(dataSec.ShipDate);
                $("#dTrack").val(dataSec.TrackingNumber);
                $("#doNote").val(dataSec.OrderNote);
                //Clean Dirty Form
                $(".dirtyForm").dirtyForms("setClean");
                constant = setInterval(function(){checkDirty()}, 500);
                //Set Table
                $(".orderDetTable").dataTable({
                    aaData: data.array,
                    "bAutoWidth": false,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "aoColumnDefs" : [
                        {"sWidth" : "13%", "sTitle" : "Quantity", "mData" : "Quantity", aTargets : [0]},
                        {"sTitle" : "Code", "mData" : "Code", aTargets : [1]},
                        {"sTitle" : "Amount", "mData" : "Amount", aTargets : [2]},
                        {"sWidth" : "6%", "sTitle" : "", "mData" : "OrderDetailsID", aTargets : [3], "mRender" : function(data, type, full){
                            return "<a href='#'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil orderDetEdit' id='"+data+"'></i></a>";
                        }}
                    ]
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is the stack trace for the facebox call.

```
$.facebox@http://dev.mysite.info/details.php?id=63#:540
.DirtyForms.dialog.fire@http://dev.mysite.info/assets/js/jquery.dirtyforms.js:25
bindFn@http://dev.mysite.info/assets/js/jquery.dirtyforms.js:421
aBindFn@http://dev.mysite.info/assets/js/jquery.dirtyforms.js:311
jQuery.event.dispatch@http://dev.mysite.info/assets/js/jquery.js:5095
jQuery.event.add/elemData.handle@http://dev.mysite.info/assets/js/jquery.js:4766
```

Comment: have you got your answer?

Comment: Are you referencing face box? It's used by default by the plugin

Comment: The error message is suspiciously similar to the one in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885368/facebox-only-works-once

Comment: "when I recall the ajax function to load the form with more info" - What does the code like like?

Comment: @zeroflagL I added the function.

Comment: Can you also show us the stacktrace?

Comment: Are you displaying a message using face box? Can you post it?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I myself have not written even a piece of code for facebox. As far as I know, it must be the dirtyForms.js that is using it. Hmm, I'm starting to wonder. Does dirtyForms.js need other libraries that I'm not giving it? namely, facebox?

Comment: Ok, first of all, the docs for dirtyForm.js should have let me know that I needed to include the facebox library. unfortunately, I had never ran into this before so I didn't know what it was. I shall know in the future... :) But what I really need to know is how to keep dirty forms from trying to make those popups in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to call `setClean` after changing anything in the form including data tables.

---

If it's just the error, then here's a hack. This will get you by if you're under a deadline, and will also help you debug:

```
if ( typeof $.facebox !== 'function' )
{
    $.facebox = function(){
        var console = window['console'];
        if ( console && console.error ){
            console.error( 'Warning: $.facebox() was called', arguments );
        }
        return $();
    }
}
```

Another tip: If you include the same jQuery library more than once, your plugins may not work.

To solve that, do a search for all instances of jquery in your codebase using this magic:

```
grep -o 'jquery:[^"]*"1\....' -R *
```

This searches for the jQuery.fn.version string.

---

You also need to check that the plugin is working. Try checking the following:

- Is the plugin added after jQuery? - [JQuery plugin not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374645/jquery-plugin-not-working)
- Does the plugin support your version of jQuery? - [Why is the lightbox jQuery plugin not working for me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16138766/why-is-the-lightbox-jquery-plugin-not-working-for-me)
- Is more than one copy of jQuery included on the page? That can cause things to go crazy.
  Read: [jQuery in widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587751/jquery-in-widget)

---

EDIT: To get a stacktrace to see what's calling the facebox function:

```
$.facebox = function(){
    alert( new Error().stack );
};
```

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but it seems to be expecting something back from facebox to continue. Like maybe a confirm.

Comment: OK I updated the answer with some tips on how to get the plugin working. It might be a headache, but it would be worth reading the the links I referenced.

Comment: I already have Facebox working. What I need is some way for dirtyforms.js to not try to bring up the dialogs because I don't need them and they are getting in the way.

Comment: It's important to know where the facebox is being triggered. Is it called during the `dataTable()` call? Is it called before the Ajax response/success function? jQuery allows you to attach a function to every Ajax response. (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: `console.error()` usually gives a stacktrace. Can you include it in your question?

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the stack trace. How would I use that? like, where in the code that I have up, and what to put in the (). Sorry, I've never used it before. And also, does this only work in FF?

Comment: I added a code snippet. Try running that. Perhaps you can see what code you will need to remove on your site in the stack trace. Could you post the stack trace it gives you?

Comment: Ok, I posted the stack trace.

Comment: OK the stacktrace indicates that the call is coming from dirtyforms. Do you have the latest version of DirtyForms in your site?

Comment: Yes. I downloaded it just recently.

Comment: Based on the stacktrace, it's clearly an issue with DirtyForms. Maybe there's an option in their API

Comment: Getting DirtyForms to not show a dialog is beyond the scope of your question. DirtyForms is designed to prompt the user when the form is "dirty"

Comment: Or is the dialog coming up because the form is not being set to clean properly? Let me analyze this....

Comment: If that's the case, then make sure that `setClean` is after the dataTable call at the very *end* of the function. (I'll update my answer.)

Comment: Actually, the dataTable is not part of the dirty form, so it wouldn't make a difference whether it was before or after that. The part that is in the form is right after the comment //Set main fields. Anyways, thanks for your help. I guess I'll post a second question concerning how to stop dirtyForms from creating popup boxes.

Comment: I'd hate for you to not find a solution, so I'll do what I can to help.

Comment: Thanks very much. Here is the link to my other question if you want it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20887320/how-to-disable-popup-alerts-on-dirtyforms-js I'm wondering If I should link back to this question in case someone wants to look at the code I posted here.

Comment: I would just copy and paste the relevant parts of the code and a link to the site that you downloaded DirtyForms from. Even a screenshot....

Comment: I think I'm starting to figure things out. I don't think I'll need anymore help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to enable/disable the buttons when the form is dirty/clean is now posted in the [official documentation](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#usage). Do note that this only works with Dirty Forms 2.x.

```
// Enable/disable the reset and submit buttons when the state transitions
// between dirty and clean. You will need to first set the initial button
// state to disabled (either in JavaScript or by setting the attributes in HTML).
$('form').find('[type="reset"],[type="submit"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
$('form').on('dirty.dirtyforms clean.dirtyforms', function (ev) {
    var $form = $(ev.target);
    var $submitResetButtons = $form.find('[type="reset"],[type="submit"]');
    if (ev.type === 'dirty') {
        $submitResetButtons.removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $submitResetButtons.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Also, it is pretty clear from your error message that you are using the default Dirty Forms 1.x behavior, which uses FaceBox as the dialog, but you don't have a reference in your page to FaceBox. You could fix that by adding the reference:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.facebox/1.4.1/jquery.facebox.min.js"></script>
```

Alternatively, you can use any dialog you want by setting the [`$.DirtyForms.dialog` property](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms#dialogs), or you can set it to false to use the browser's default dialog.

```
$.DirtyForms.dialog = false;
```

In Dirty Forms 2.x, `false` is now the default setting, so there is no need to add a reference to FaceBox.